# Replace sheet name with gid number in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I want to replace the sheet name with gid number in Google Sheets.

`=importrange("1anqeokmYsrtsdssdsx9QHOXqoVkgio254O8","Sheet1!K5:M5")`

How can I replace the Sheet1! with its gid number?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) doesn't use GID, only the sheet name.

If you want to use GID instead of using a built-in function, you should use a custom function, a script or an add-on.

For further details see

- [Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)
- [Install, use & uninstall add-ons](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3641454?hl=en)